# Determining the time complexity of this program

Tags: time-complexity

```cpp
void f2(int n)
{
    if (n<=1)
        return;
        g2(n, n/3);
}
void g2(int n, int m)
{
    int i=1;
    while (m < n) {
        m += i;
        i++;
    }
    f2(n/2);
}
```

I tried alot to calculate the time complexity and got it wrong, I would really appreciate it if someone could help me on how to approach these programs. (The answer is `O(sqrt(n)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following explanation can be simplified, but I tried to be as much scrupulous as possible.

### Sum of arithmetic progression

First of all lets talk about complixity of the following loop (note the `m=0`):

```cpp
int m=0;
int i=1;
while (m < n) {
    m += i;
    i++;
}
```

Invariant of the loop is: after `i`th iteration `m == 1+2+...+i == (1+i)*i/2`. So the loop stops when the following condition is met:

[image: i(i-1)/2 < n <= (i+1)i/2]

which is equavalent to

[image: sqrt(i(i-1)/2) < sqrt(n) <= sqrt((i+1)i/2)]

Big O of the left and right parts are equal and both equal to `O(i)`, so `O(i)=O(sqrt(n))` is the complexity of the loop.

### Complexity of the loop inside g2

The loop inside the `g2` is equavalent to the following loop:

```cpp
int n_modified = n - m;
m = 0;
int i=1;
while (m < n_modified) {
    m += i;
    i++;
}
```

which complexity is `O(sqrt(n-m))` as we've shown in the previous section.

### Complexity of the f2

Now lets get overall formula for complexity of the `f2` function. Its complexity is essentially the same as complexity of the `g2(n, n/3)` call. It consists of two parts: complexity of the `g2`'s loop and complexitiy of the recursion. That is, the formula is

[image: Complexity of f2]

This can be simplified and estimated (factoring and sum of geometric progression):

[image: Factorizing, estimating, sum of geometric progression]

which gives us the final answer: the complexity of `f2` is `O(sqrt(n))`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me alot, took me a long time (probably read it like 10 times and tried until I think it sinked in), still new to time complexity in general. I got a couple of questions just to make sure I really understood it the right way: 1) about the sum of the loop you mentioned, You are actually calculating how many iterations there is until the loop is done (which is only when the sum of the i's is bigger or equal to n), and our goal is to find at which i value this happens, for that reason we take the square root?

Comment: 2) Also wanted to ask about the way of looking at programs in general, I noticed that the first thing I should do is go through the program until I reach the most inner loop (that probably will decide the time complexity of the program) and then go back and use it to calculate the time complexity of the rest of the program. I would really appreciate any tips or maybe some names of known basic programs that I should know in order to be able to analyze bigger and more complicated programs.

Comment: @Pwaol (1) - correct. (2) Merge sort, HeapSort, Dijkstra's algorithm, operations on some binary search tree (like red-black tree). I recommend to read a book Cormen, Thomas "Introduction to Algorithms" in which you will find a lot of standard algorithms with time complexity analyses.

Comment: @Doj where did you learn time complexity from? Please can share source. Explaination was really good.

Comment: @Shad I cannot name one specific source, there were many of them. And experience - some competitive programming in the past. But if I wanted to learn time complexity from scratch right now, I would take some good book about algorithms or computer science. Thomas Cormen "Introduction to Algorithms" as I mentioned above, Donald Knuth "The Art of Computer Programming", Alexander Shen "Algorithms and Programming: Problems and Solutions" etc.